# Python/Pygame: Trying to use a variable (maybe holding a string) to represent a PyGame condition

Tags: python, keyboard, pygame, customization, keyword

This is my first post sorry in advance for any etiquette missteps.

I am currently using pygame in Python to allow the user to customise what keys do what. The code below is my current condition but it does not solve the problem I'm having.

```
 if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
```

What I actually want is something more like this:

```
if keys["pygame.customisable_key"]:
```

As far as I know the pygame preface has to be included because of the way I'm designing the class that import this one.

Thanks

Comment: It's unclear what this code is trying to *do*.  If I'm understanding correctly, you would like the user of this pygame application to customize their key layout, so rather than checking for the "K" key here, it should depend on the user settings.  If so, then what you want to do is introduce a variable above and have it be set to one of the constants defined in the pygame library.  You also don't want quotes as that will turn the expression from "a constant defined in the pygame module" to an arbitrary string literal that will give undesired effects when used as a dictionary key here.

Comment: Sorry that this was unclear, as honestly I'm having trouble figuring out what to do. I'm aware that the quotes makes the expression a string, I just put those there to show that I'm fine with anything in that section being changed. I'm also not checking for the key "K", that signifies Key Up. The problem is that pygame has pretty specific keys and they're not strings as far as I can tell so I can't have the user enter something and then deal with their input that way. Essentially I'm trying to convert user input to something pygame will recognise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`pygame.K_`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html) constants are actually just numbers (integers) which you can put as the values into your `keys` dictionary.

I'd define a dictionary with the actions (strings) as the dict keys and the pygame key constansts as the values, e.g.: `keys = {'move_left': pg.K_a, 'move_right': pg.K_d}`.

Then you can check in the event loop `if event.key == keys['move_left']:` and handle that event as desired.

To change a key, you first need to figure out to which action a new key should be assigned and when the next keyboard key gets pressed, insert the `event.key` attribute as the new value: `keys[selected_action] = event.key`.

This is just a simplistic example which can still be improved, but it's complete and works correctly as far as I can see (Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to toggle the assignment scene, press one of the previous keys to select an action and then another key to assign a new key to this action):

```
import sys
import pygame as pg


def key_assignment_scene(keys, screen, clock):
    selected_action = None

    while True:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                pg.quit()
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pg.K_ESCAPE:
                    return keys  # Return the keys to the main scene.
                elif selected_action:
                    # Assign a new key to the action.
                    keys[selected_action] = event.key
                    print(keys, 'new key:', event.unicode)
                    selected_action = None
                else:  # Select an action (a key from the `keys` dict).
                    for action, pygame_key in keys.items():
                        if event.key == pygame_key:
                            selected_action = action
                            print('Selected action:', selected_action)

        screen.fill((20, 40, 60))
        pg.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)


def main():
    pg.init()
    screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    BG_COLOR = pg.Color('gray12')
    BLUE = pg.Color('dodgerblue1')
    rect = pg.Rect(300, 220, 20, 20)
    speed_x = 0
    keys = {'move_left': pg.K_a, 'move_right': pg.K_d}

    while True:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                return
            elif event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pg.K_ESCAPE:
                    print(keys)
                    # Switch to the key assigment scene.
                    keys = key_assignment_scene(keys, screen, clock)
                elif event.key == keys['move_left']:
                    speed_x = -3
                elif event.key == keys['move_right']:
                    speed_x = 3
            elif event.type == pg.KEYUP:
                if event.key == keys['move_left'] and speed_x < 0:
                    speed_x = 0
                elif event.key == keys['move_right'] and speed_x > 0:
                    speed_x = 0

        rect.x += speed_x

        screen.fill(BG_COLOR)
        pg.draw.rect(screen, BLUE, rect)
        pg.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)

main()
pg.quit()
```